# Invalid token in ASP.NET CORE 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to confirm the email, but the moment I try to confirm it, it indicates that the token is invalid, validate the token with a stop point and it is correct, I do not know what could be happening,

This is my method that sends me the email with the user and the token,

[image]

This is the method when I am trying to confirm the email and it is the one that tells me that the invalid token,

[image]

Try encoding the token with url encode and it didn't work for me, I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are creating new users right before your generate the token, its relying on the security stamp which is expected to be stable . So instead of create a new `User` entity , directly get user from database :

```
var myUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
string mytoken= await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(myUser);
```

Comment: understood I did, as you indicated and it worked, now a question why I can not create a new user even if it passes the same data

Comment: Creating new instance user won't include the security stamp which token validation rely on .